# Extra blank page with Bayesian Analysis journal style file

Tags: debugging, journal-publishing, journal

See the following MWE, which uses the [Bayesian Analysis journal style file.](http://bayesian.org/webfm_send/264).

```
\documentclass[bib]{ba}
\inserttype[ba0001]{article}
\begin{document}
\title[Short Version]{Long Version}
\author{\fnms{Faheem} \snm{Mitha}\ead[label=e1]{faheem@faheem.info}}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  foo
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

This generates a two page PDF for me. If I remove the blank line, or add a % on the blank line, this becomes one page. This seems like surprising behavior to me.
Can anyone tell me if this is a bug, and if not, how should I work around it?

Comment: @HarishKumar If you remove the blank line, do you get one page?

Comment: @HarishKumar yes, the question is why it goes from two pages to one page. My MWE may have been a little too minimal.

Comment: @HarishKumar Sorry, my long and short was transposed. I've fixed it now.

Comment: You get one page at the beginning with the long title and not much else. Then the second page starts with the short title.

Comment: @HarishKumar You're right. My bad. Now, when I remove that space, the title disappears altogether. Do you get that too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[bib]{ba}
\inserttype[ba0001]{article}   
\begin{document}
\title[Short Version]{Long Version}       %% this line
\author{faheem}
 {\fnms{Faheem} \snm{Mitha}\footnotemark[1]\ead{faheem@faheem.info}}    %% this line

\maketitle

\footnotetext[1]{Affiliation First Author}    %% this added.
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}   %% this may be needed.
\begin{abstract}
  foo
\end{abstract}



\end{document}
```

[image]

What went wrong?

1. The title should be

   ```
   \title[Short article title]{Long title for title page of article insert}
   ```

   Note the brackets around short title.
2. The author should be

   ```
    \author{authors}{their details line \snms etc}
   ```
3. `\ead[label=e1]{faheem@faheem.info}}` shouldn't have label but a `footnotemark`

Comment: I see. So that extra footnote stuff makes a difference?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes don't use `label`s

Comment: Ok. I guess this is usage error, then. I was using an earlier style, and I guess I didn't change properly to the style. Sorry for the noise, and thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: @FaheemMitha It certainly looks like usage error :(